# DNN 7.4: Error instalando en contenido para 2sxc 10

Tags: 2sxc

I tell you to install DNN 7.4 then when I want to install the module contained for 2sxc 10 I get an error. (Attached image)

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWNI.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need more than an image. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if 2sxc 10 is compatible with DNN 7, but in any case I recommend you to disregard so old versions of DNN, as they're no longer supported neither updated . This is a serious issue when it comes to security and performance, not to mention that you'll lose any modern technologies that you can use with most recent versions of DNN. Therefore, I encourage you to install DNN version 9.6.0, which is the most recent one, and take advantage of all its functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

2sxc works all the way down to DNN 7.4.2.

But @Perezandres is correct - DNN 7 is not really secure, or you need to do a lot of hardening to keep it safe. Better to start with 9.6.1

In regards to your error, I assume you were using DNN 7.4.2, otherwise you wouldn't be able to install 2sxc. But the error you see I cannot explain just like that. Best repeat the procedure with F12 running, and show what you get back. Also check the DNN Admin logs and see what you get there.